# How to scrape all TR Elements and all TD Elements from several URLs? May require Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm having trouble with the loop (seems to be 0 all the time) and I'm not even getting the TR and TD elements from page 0, so something is definitely wrong with my script.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

cnt = 0
# count from 0 to 3
while (cnt < 4):
    url = "https://www.anyurl/admin/?page=" + str(cnt)
    print(cnt)
    page = requests.get(url)
    pagetext = page.text
    # print(pagetext)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(pagetext, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup)

    file = open("C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/test.csv", 'w')

    for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
        for col in row.find_all('td'):
            info1 = row.text
            info2 = col.text
            file.write(info1)
            file.write(info2)

    print(cnt)        
    cnt = cnt + 1

    file.close()
```

I think the code above is pretty close, but something is definitely off here.

I may need to go with a Selenium solution, like this...

```
import requests
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webbot import Browser
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

web = Browser()
cnt = 0
# count from 0 to 3
while (cnt < 4):
    url = "https://www.anyurl/admin/?page=" + str(cnt)
    web.go_to(url)
    time.sleep(2)

    # 1st validation
    web.type('my.email@gmail.com', into='username')
    web.click('Next')
    # Wait for 2 seconds
    time.sleep(2)

    # password
    web.type('my_password', into='Password')
    web.click('Next')
    time.sleep(2)



    Somehow...I need to iterate through TR elements and TD elements here....

    cnt = cnt + 1
```

What I know for sure, is that there is a table that has this name: `table id="dags"`

Also, the TR and TD pieces alternate like this:

[image]

TR classes alternate as 'odd' and 'even'.

Basically, I am trying to count from 0 to 3, scrape all TR elements and all TE elements, and write all into a CSV file.  This is an internal URL, behind a corporate firewall, so I can't share the actual one here.

I am on Python 3.6.

Comment: What's is the problem exactly? Is it just that the cnt seems to be 0 all the time or are you getting empy values while scraping the tr and td elements?

Comment: To check if you need Selenium I recommend to check the source code of the page and check if the tr and td elements are available. If they're not then you probably need Selenium since it's a JavaScript rendered page

Comment: Yes, yes, I got the cnt issue figured out.  I can't scrape all TR and TD elements.  I think, in the first scenario, I wasn't logged into the site, so I literally couldn't grab anything (although the site administrator claims that once you are logged in you are always logged in).  I think it has more to do with something in JavaScript...I think the tables are dynamically generated.  I think that's the real issue here.  So, I believe the real question is, how can I scrape TR elements and TD elements using Selenium???

Comment: Try use soup.select(table tr). If this give no results then yes you should use Selenium

Comment: Yes, i ended up going with Selenium and that worked out for me.  Why, exactly, would you need to use that?  It seems like the tables are generated dynamically, or some such thing.  How can the browser see it, yet base Python can't see it?  Thanks.

Comment: All I know is that requests only has access to the source code. Dynamically rendered pages mostly have script tags in source code. That is why you cant use requests and bs4. Selenium on the other hand is acting like a real "person" browsing through the internet. In this case the tables are generated and the tags are visible

Answer (score 0):

Do check out the following pages:

**Getting Started**
(The standard stuffs to kick off your script)
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Once you've init-ed your driver, you can locate the contents by the methods found here: 
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

In your case, you probably need something like below; loop through the list and write the contents to file.

> td_list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')